# Style Button as inline text in react-native

Tags: css, react-native, button

I have the following code using the `Text` and `Button` components from `react-native-paper`:

```
<Text>See also </Text>
<Button mode="text" compact onPress={this.nav( name )}>Compass</Button>
<Text> on how to use the Compass.</Text>
```

When rendered this results in:

[image]

If I replace the `Button` with `TouchableOpacity` or alike the result looks like:

[image]

How can I style the `Button` or `TouchableOpacity` so it's not offset in regard to the surrounding text?

UPDATE

Using the example from @RajendranNadar and after fixing so it runs on android:

```
See also <Pressable onPress={() => alert('Hello :)')}><Text style={styles.text}>Compass</Text></Pressable> on how to use the Compass.
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Have you already considered to avoid the <Button> and to use a <Text> (properly styled) with an `onPress` prop?

Comment: Pressable element is the best choice in your case

Comment: @Milore I started with that. The problem is, that the `<Text onPress={blah()}>link</Text>` is hard to hit, only the letters are active, but not the space between or around them

Comment: @injecteer are you using any UI library for typography if you are importing from react native?

Comment: @RajendranNadar I'm using `react-native-paper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use nested texts. Something like this:

```
const NestedText = () => {
  return (
    <Text>See also <Text style={styles.link} onPress={() => {}}>Compass</Text> on how to use the Compass.</Text>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  link: {
    color: 'blue',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  }
});
```

Comment: this way only the letters are active, but not it's surroundings. For example the letter O is not clickable inside

Comment: This way works well using the base React Native text component - see this snack: https://snack.expo.dev/VkcDzMzmv .  The problem you're experiencing might be an artifact of React Native Paper.

Comment: @Abe please put your comment with the code from your snack, so I can accept it as an answer. I tested it and it works like charm!

Comment: Glad it worked! I could, but isn't it the same as the answer we're commenting on?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best approach to using the `Pressable` component from the react-native package

```
<Text>
  See also <Pressable onPress={() => alert('Hello')}>Compass</Pressable> on how to use the Compass.
</Text>
```

Check the live demo here https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/pressable-example

[Pressable component docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Comment: On android it complains, that the text must be rendered inside the Text component. If I put the `<Text>` inside `<Pressable>` I'm getting the same vertical offset I encountered with my original sample

Comment: Updated the question with your sample

Comment: @injecteer this answer is working, just remove your styles from the `<Text>` inside the `<Pressable>`. this is working fine `<Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        See also <Pressable style={styles.text} onPress={() => alert('Hello :)')}>
        <Text>Compass</Text>
        </Pressable> on how to use the Compass.
      </Text>`

Answer (score 0):

this is full working example.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Linking,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
```

---

```
const PrivacyPolicy = ({title = 'GET STARTED'}) => {
  const openUrl = async () => {
    let url = 'https://facebook.com';
    await Linking.canOpenURL(url)
      .then(() => Linking.openURL(url))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        By Pressing The "{title}" You Accept
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => openUrl()}>
          <Text style={styles.text2}> Privacy Policy </Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        And
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => openUrl()}>
          <Text style={{...styles.text2}}> End User License Agreement</Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PrivacyPolicy;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH - moderateScale(20),
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: moderateScale(10),
  },
  text: {
   
    includeFontPadding: false,
    fontSize: moderateScale(12),
  },
  text2: {
   
    fontSize: moderateScale(12),
    includeFontPadding: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: this way the text is hardly clickable, see the comments above